# style a website in a iframe or not hosted by me?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

What is the best and easyest way to stlye a website that is not hosted by me?

i use a 3rd party website for contact forms but the styling is UGLY. i am wanting to put this in an iframe and style the site but have tried and failed. i have looked at other questions on here but cant seem to get it to work

this is what i got so far

```
<script>
var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
cssLink.href = "style.css";  cssLink .rel = "stylesheet";  
cssLink .type = "text/css";  
frames['frame1'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink); 
</script>

<iframe src="domain.com" width="200" height="200" frame id="frame1"></iframe>
```

i have also created a css named style.css

for example if the page im styling has a div class of example1 i would put this on my new css
what have i done wrong or is there another way to style this?

Comment: Just to clarify: your page imports this iframe from 3rd party, but you want to add a link in the iframe that loads CSS from your domain?

Comment: The reason you did not find a solution is that there really isn't any. The only possible way is to make a proxy server and modify the styles. But you don't want to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change style of iframe content cross-domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724904/how-to-change-style-of-iframe-content-cross-domain)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not do it because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).