# how to write css for inner html of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

have one question, i trapped in a prob..The problem is like that --->I have to manipulate the css of inner html of iframe but the content of this iframe is not coming from same domain so how can it makes possible
live eg.-u can take ("tweets feed in our website ,it comes from another domain tweeter.com/bla....blaa but render on our web page encapsulate with iframe,so how can i style tweet section in our website")
i have tried by jQuery but its not working can u plz help me out in that ?
Thanks in advance Smile | :)

Comment: You need to post your code with your questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724904/how-to-change-style-of-iframe-content-cross-domain

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Sico refers to an existing question on stack that answers this as not possible. [How to change style of iframe content cross-domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724904/how-to-change-style-of-iframe-content-cross-domain)

If you are looking to do this in Javascript or JQuery that answer is correct, basically. You Cannot. It is not possible to alter the content of another domain.

A solution however, would be to use PHP to fetch the content of the target page and make it your own, there are several ways to do this such as curl http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php. You can then redisplay that content in any manner you like and apply any style you like. You can even ditch the iframe and inline it right into the rest of your content.

Be warned however, depending on the source domain, they may not approve of their content being re-used in this manner.