# apply css to iframe(no control over this domian) using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website example.com and another website example1.com. i want to display example1.com as the iframe content in example.com site.

For example:

Include this in example.com `<iframe src='http://example1.com'>`

and add the jquery script in end of body in example.com. this is not working in cross domain. so any tweaks to this please

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Frame").load(function(){
    var timestamp =  +(new Date());
    $("#Frame").contents().find("head").append("<link href='http://xxxxxx.com/style.css?&apos;+ timestamp +&apos;' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>");
  });
});
```

so when the example1.com iframe loads in example.com the xxxxxx.com/style.css must be included in the header of example1.com iframe to change its css content

**NOTE: I don't have control over example1.com which is the iframe content**

The CMS i am using doesn't allow me access the server side. So manipulation can be done at the client side only. So solution like using proxy won't help.

I know about cross domian policy. but even some people do manipulate. thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: I think it will not work on cross-domain due to security issues

Comment: No until you have some control over both domain. http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using CSS to affect div style inside iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change style of iframe content cross-domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724904/how-to-change-style-of-iframe-content-cross-domain)

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility would be to load the iframe content through a proxy of yours and modify the HTML content. You can not access iframes from another domain via JavaScript.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4724942/4711865)
[Reference2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 0):

Warning : This might not work as browsers implement and remove this feature more or less regularly.
One thing that you *might* do but which can break your website design (I would not recommend doing that unless you *REALLY* do not have any other choice) : use the **seamless** attribute on the iframe and enforce CSS styles with important on the elements you want modified.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

I believe that it is really not that well supported, and I provide this information as a thing to try if every other failed.

Comment: The `seamless` attribute is like you say next to [not supported at all](http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-seamless). Also it seams the owner of the `<iframe>` content will be able to [actively disable this feature](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#sandboxed-seamless-iframes-flag) on their site. This concept may also results in serious security concerns.

Comment: Definitly, hence all the warnings and disclaimers :) As a side-note W3 still displays the seamless attribute in the doc (http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-seamless), but it is mentioned as "at risk of being dropped due to the lack of implementation" in discussions. In any case, I pointed out that it existed and *could* work in some environments (if you can enforce the use of a specific browser in a specific version) and that I would not recommend using it anyway :)