# Accessing facebook through iframe tag and getting a cross origin error

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i'm testing this in local host and its getting cross origin error.. how to resolve this problem help me i'm the beginner and i don't have knowledge about that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function iframeLoaded()
  {
      var iFrameID = document.getElementById('idIframe');
      if (iFrameID) 
      {
         iFrameID.height = "";
         iFrameID.height =iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
</script>

<iframe onload="iframeLoaded()" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.facebook.com/palletech" frameborder="1"..../>
```

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724904/how-to-change-style-of-iframe-content-cross-domain

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This is by design, access to content served from other *origins* (domains, etc.) is protected by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). For you to access it from your page on your origin, the other site would have to explicitly give you access, which Facebook will not do.

Comment: i have to fix the height of iframe based on its content(accessing from facebook ) is it possible?

Comment: @AnushaGajulapalli: You can't access the window or document object of the frame, because they aren't yours. You can change the height of *your frame*, but you can't use information from Facebook's stuff to do it.

Comment: how  to change the height property other than  using styles

Comment: @AnushaGajulapalli: Use any other information you want. But for the third time, you cannot use information from the Facebook frame.