# Scroll to top of parent from iframe on different domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I have an iframe embedded in a page. They are both on different domains but I have access to both.

I want to scroll to the top of the parent window when a link is clicked in the iframe. Somthing like this:

Within the Iframe page.

```
window.parent.ScrollToTop(); // Scroll to top function
```

On The parrent page:

```
window.ScrollToTop = function(){
  $('html,body', window.document).animate({
    scrollTop: '0px'
    }, 'fast');
  };
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: The Same Origin Policy prevents you from accessing the windows cross-domain to call any such methods. The way to do this is to use `postMessage` to have the iframe send a message to the parent, and then the parent can scroll itself.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have access to parent domain** then you can use this:

```
window.top.scroll(0,0)
```

or if you want some animation use as:

```
$(window.top.document).find("body").animate({
scrollTop: 0
}, 600);
```

Comment: I have access to both but they are on different domains. Therefore when I try and call window.parent it gives an error about cross-domains.

Comment: yes, it will show because Javascript doesn't allow to change any behavior of one domain through some other domain.
For more info, please check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724904/how-to-change-style-of-iframe-content-cross-domain