# Show a specific part of an iFrame using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```html
<iframe src = "https://newsela.com"></iframe>
```

I don't want the menu that's shown above.

Is there a way to do that with JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Probably not, unless your page is also hosted at `https://newsela.com`. The contents of the iframe are protected by the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), which prevents manipulation by other sites/origins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that :

var myIFrame = document.getElementById("my_iframe");

var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document;

content.getElementById("header").style.display = "none";

You will have to do a proxy on your server to have the same domain name

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want! Thank you very much!

Comment: Does that work? Shouldn't that be blocked due to cross-origin?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724904/how-to-change-style-of-iframe-content-cross-domain