# javascript get Google reCAPTCHA v3 token from iframe

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

How can I get the recaptcha token from inside the iframe and put it in the input?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change style of iframe content cross-domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724904/how-to-change-style-of-iframe-content-cross-domain) (It may be about styles, but the answer is the same)

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, I want to get the token value with javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe)

Comment: @Mohammad that's what I'm telling you. You can't if you're not on the same domain