# manipulate child inside tag <iframe> in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, next.js

for now my page is rendered like the picture

[image: 1]

I have a code like this but the css doesn't effect to the child in iframe, i'm using NextJS by the way.

```
const HomeMain = () => {
  

  const css = ` 
    #mindMap html body {
      transform: matrix(0.6, 0, 0, 0.6, -436.686, 19.6857); backface-visibility: visible; transform-origin: 50% 50%; cursor: move; transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    }
  `;

  return (
        <div className="tw-w-full tw-rounded-2xl tw-p-4 tw-bg-white tw-h-full tw-row-span-4">
          <iframe
            id="mindMap"
            datatype="html"
            src="https://cdn.extramarks.id/content_data/mind_map/2019/11/08/2333124/dir_2333124/index.html"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
          ></iframe>
          <style>{css}</style>
        </div>
  );
};
```

i want to make the iframe content fit the container, this is my expect

[image: 2]

, what should i do? any answers will be help me.

Comment: The short answer is that you won't be able to [apply CSS styles to an iframe from a different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724904/how-to-change-style-of-iframe-content-cross-domain). You could apply the scaling transform to the iframe itself but that will also scale the heading.

Comment: yeah i've try to scale the iframe it self, but yeah it doesn't help, thanks for the suggestion